# I am trying to deploy a CloudTrail trail with a s3 bucket with a bucket policy and also a KMS key with a key policy. This error that I get. help pleaz

Tags: key, policy

Resource handler returned message: "The new key policy will not allow you to update the key policy in the future. (Service: Kms, Status Code: 400, Request ID: fffca946-89f0-49f2-9d22-e07b4480adf1)" (RequestToken: 508392d1-3b13-77a0-0b29-e22d157a58ca, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the problem is the current key policy will not allow the key to be deployed in cloudformation and it is given me the error above

Comment: thanks for responding. im new here